# How to make following chapter heading style

Tags: chapters

In an older Czech book I found the following chapter and section heading style. Is it possible to do something like that in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a durt way to do this using `titlesec` and `tikz` (for the vertical rules around the chapter name).

Maybe someone have a better idea.

The result is: [image]

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Kapitola}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{4cm}{-18pt}{10ex}[4cm]
\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{0pt}{0ex}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\LARGE\bfseries}{\itshape\chaptertitlename\ \Roman{chapter}}{8ex}{\large\MakeUppercase{#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        % Left Rule
        \coordinate (L1) at ([xshift=3.5cm]current page text area.north west);
        \coordinate (L2) at ([yshift=-3pt]0,0);
        \draw [line width=.8pt] (L1) -- ($(L1)!(L2)!(L1)$);
        % Right Rule
        \coordinate (R1) at ([xshift=-3.5cm]current page text area.north east);
        \coordinate (R2) at ([yshift=-3pt]0,0);
        \draw [line width=.8pt] (R1) -- ($(R1)!(R2)!(R1)$);
        %% Auxiliaries Rules
        % \draw (L1) -- (R1)
        % \draw (R1) |- (R2);
        % \draw (L1) |- (L2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\filcenter}{\large\bfseries § \arabic{section}}{1ex}{\addtolength{\titlewidth}{-12ex}\titleline*[c]{\titlerule[.8pt]}\vspace{1ex}\itshape #1}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{5}% Next chapter: 6

\chapter{Besselova Rovnice}

\section{Besselovy funkce l. druhu}

\end{document}
```

I think only miss adjust the letters type.